# NSJSONSerialization crashing app

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I have a dictionary that when I log it shows...

```
{
    Date = "2013-04-30 17:17:18 +0000";
    Description = Kb;
    EventID = "92193e58-c04a-4233-9a6c-1332bc056b20";
    Title = Keyboard;
}
```

I'm trying to turn it into NSData for a JSON web service like this...

```
- (NSData *)JSONRepresentation
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [self dictionaryObject];

    NSError *jsonError;

    NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:&jsonError];  //This is where the error occurs.

    return JSONData;
}
```

But every time I run it the app just crashes.

The dictionary is formed properly, the app just crashes at this line.

In AppCode I get the crash report...

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe))
```

In Xcode the app just stops and if I try to continue it stops with an error...

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

Comment: Where does the debugger show it blowing up?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context, e.g. the surrounding lines?  Where is `jsonError` declared?

Comment: On the line `NSData *JSONData = [NSJSON....`. It stops at that line. In the debugger after the crash I printed out the dictionary so the dictionary is definitely correct.

Comment: Added the entire function.

Comment: NSLog "dictionary" just before the call.

Comment: Does this project use ARC or not?

Comment: @HotLicks That's what I have done. It is printed in the question.

Comment: @Jim yes it uses ARC.

Comment: Are your keys NSString instances? If not this will probably not work.

Comment: @sosborn They are NSString and NSDate instances. Does the NSDate break it? Shouldn't that just display the error in the jsonError? Will try changing it to NSString now.

Comment: NSDate will break it. Other values should be OK. Here is the list from the docs: `All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.`

Comment: D'oh! Thanks, I have changed it now... and it works! Thanks very much! Not sure why it doesn't just populate the NSError that is passed in though?! Stick it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Thanks. By the way I know this because I got burned by it last night :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your keys are invalid objects for converting to JSON. [From the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary. All objects are
>   instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull. All
>   dictionary keys are instances of NSString. Numbers are not NaN or
>   infinity.

Comment: Thanks very much. The NSDate object was causing the crash.

Comment: Great. I had a swift enum that I forgot to pass as a string rawValue which caused this crash for me.

Answer (score 1):

check before, if the dictionary is invalid to convert, return.:

`if (![NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dictionary]) { return; }`